# Convert PHP to Python

Tags: python, hash, sha1

I need help converting the following PHP to python

```
$plaintext = "MyPassword";
$utf_text = mb_convert_encoding( $plaintext, 'UTF-16LE' );
$sha1_text = sha1( $utf_text, true );
$base64_text = base64_encode( $sha1_text );
echo $base64_text; //ouput = QEy4TXy9dNgleLq+IEcjsQDYm0A=
```

1. Convert the string to UTF16LE
2. Hash the output of 1. using SHA1
3. Encode the output of 2. using base64 encoding.

Im trying hashlib.sha1 but its not working. Maybe due to this, maybe encodings. Can anyone help

Comment: *but its not working* is **not** an error description. What code did you try, what was the output, what did you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your PHP code encodes the password to UTF16, little endian; if your password value is a unicode value, that works just fine in Python:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> plaintext = u"MyPassword"
>>> utf_text = plaintext.encode('UTF-16LE')
>>> hashlib.sha1(utf_text).digest().encode('base64')
'QEy4TXy9dNgleLq+IEcjsQDYm0A=\n'
```

The above session was done in Python 2; in Python 3 the `u` prefix can be omitted as all string values are Unicode.

Comment: my password value is in unicode - so i dont need that step - thanks.

Comment: @Mark: because you didn't share your original code, it was otherwise impossible for us to point out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, i was using the hashlib.sha1 incorrectly.

```
import hashlib

password = "MYPASSWORD"
result ='QEy4TXy9dNgleLq+IEcjsQDYm0A='

utftext = password.encode("utf-16LE")
m = hashlib.sha1()
m.update(utftext)
sha1text = m.digest()
output = sha1text.encode('base64','strict')
print "output: %s" % output
print "expect: %s" % result
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this wouldn't work. This works like a charm and prints out the desired result, *QEy4TXy9dNgleLq+IEcjsQDYm0A=*

```
from hashlib import sha1
from base64 import b64encode

print(b64encode(sha1("MyPassword".encode("utf-16le")).digest()))
```